# Is there any kind of hash list in python

Tags: python, performance, list

I tried to find an answer here and in Python doc but the only things I got were questions about hashing list objects and details abaut how dicts work.

## Background

I'm developing a program that parses over a huge graphs (atm. 44K nodes, 14K of them are of any interest and they are connected by 15K edges) and have problems with performance although I allready optimized my algorithm as far as I could and now the last resort is to optimize the data structure:

```
def single_pass_build(nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        if node.__class__ in listOfRequiredClasses:
            children = get_children(node)
            for child in children:
                if child__class__ in listOfRequiredClasses:
                    add_edge(node, child)

def get_children(node):
    return [attr for attr in node.__dict__.values() if attr.__class__ in listOfRequiredClasses]
```

I still have to care about my add_connection function but even without it my program takes slightly over 10 Minutes for nothing but this iteration. For comparison: the module I get the data from generates it from an xml document in not more than 5 seconds.
I have a total of 44K object, each representing a node in a ralation graph. The objects I get have plenty attributes so I could try to optimize `get_children` to know all relevant attributes for every class or just speed up the lookup. Lists take O(n) (so if a is the number os attributes and k the number of classes in my list I get a total O(n*a*k + m*a*k)). Many of my attribute classes are not in that list so I am closer to the worst case than to the average. I'd like to speed up the lookup from O(k) to O(1) or at least O(log(k))

## Question

Knowing that a key lookup of dict should be O(log(n)) for many hash collision and with (few to) no hash collisions it becomes (almost) static. After I don't care for any values I'd like to know if there is a kind of (hash) list optimized for `x in list`?
I could use a dict with None values but with a total of 70000 lookups and greater graphs in future, every milli second counts. The space is not the big problem here because I expect ~50 classes total and in no case more than some hundred classes. In other cases, the space could be a issue too.

I don't expect the answer to be in standard Python but maby someone knows a common framework that can help or can make me believe that there is no reason at all why I can't use a dict for the job.

Comment: You need [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the builtin `set` type : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

And yes its IS in standard Python ;)

Comment: Answered my question but did not solve my problem. Seems like I underastimated the quantity of unused attributes while overestimating the class list. After I changed `get_children` to learn the usefull attributes for every class (sure hope they are the same every time - have to test it!) I needed less than a second. Introducing the set had no relevant influence (looks like the class list is tiny after all) but I will keep the set for reasons of scalability and use it at other parts of the program where I store some K of entrys and it **will** make a difference. Thanks

Comment: It seems that there is no difference between an empty dict and an empty set what makes me wonder if a dict is anything else but a set of pairs. Now I wonder if I can still use a set to store pairs if I don't intend it to become a dict. ... might be even better but is not the case.

Comment: Semantically, a `dict` is indeed an unordered collection of key,value pairs - that's even part of the official definition actually (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - with the added requirement that keys are unique (which is _also_ part of the official definition <g>). wrt/ implementation they obviously both are based on hashtables, so you can also think of sets as "value-less" dicts.